# Only select rows if at least one exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following query:

```
IF EXISTS ( SELECT  Column1 ,
                Column2
        FROM    dbo.Table1
        EXCEPT
        SELECT  Column1 ,
                Column2
        FROM    @proposedData )
BEGIN
    SELECT  Column1 ,
            Column2
    FROM    dbo.Table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT  Column1 ,
            Column2
    FROM    @proposedData
    RAISERROR('Unexpected values in proposed data',16,10)
END
```

I want to raise an error if the data that already exists in a table does not appear in a table variable. This is to make sure that my source code matches what is in a particular environment. The problem with this is that the two select queries are duplicate code. This introduces a possibility for human error - the two queries should be the same but could be different. An alternative is:

```
SELECT  Column1 ,
            Column2
    FROM    dbo.Table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT  Column1 ,
            Column2
    FROM    @proposedData
IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
BEGIN 
    RAISERROR ('Invalid ObjectType values',16,10)
END
```

However this 'pollutes' the query output as there will be an empty result set if the data is correct. So, is there way to prevent a result set being output if there are 0 rows? An idea is a stored proc that takes the select and constructs the first example query from it but was wondering there was a built in way to do it.

Thanks
Joe

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
if exists(SELECT  Column1 ,
            Column2
    FROM    dbo.Table1
    EXCEPT
    SELECT  Column1 ,
            Column2
    FROM    @proposedData)
    RAISERROR ('Invalid ObjectType values',16,10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but what I want is an output of the inconsistent data if and only if it is inconsistent.